# How do I make sure columns in a WPF Grid respect a minimum width?

Tags: wpf

I am creating a simple GUI in WPF:

[image]

I have arranged the three GUI elements in a Grid.
When I resize the window I want the width of the first and last column to stay fixed and size of the middle column to take all remaining width.
Unfortunately when I make the window really narrow; the button is hid:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,10,10" MinWidth="200">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Select..." Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="75" MinWidth="75"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Width="Auto" Height="20" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="File path:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: If the windows size is less than the label and button together what should happen ? button disappear because window is too small.

Comment: I want the window to refuse to resize to a smaller width than this.

Comment: Tried adding MinWidth to the Window (instead of the Grid)?

Comment: Setting MinWidth of the window to 240 worked. Is this how it is done in WPF? Seems cumbersome: I have to calculate the MinWidth of the window from all elements. I would have preferred if WPF did this for me: I specify that the MinWidth of the 3rd column is 85. Then WPF calculates that the MinWidth of the window is 240.

Comment: Yeah... that's not how it works... if you add 1000 items to your Window, then you certainly need some big screens.

Comment: See my updated answer... Guess that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If the Window should not be resized to a smaller width than a certain one, then define that in your Window properties.

If you want to show a ScrollViewer when the window becomes smaller than a certain size(Size of Grid), then add a ScrollViewer

**EDIT:**

What you can do is to Bind your Window.MinWidth = the ActualWidth of the Grid.

Name your grid something:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
```

And then bind your window midwidth like this:

```
 MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneTime}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately with this change the window will not resize to less than width approximately = 600 pixels!?